# Div debajo de otro que ocupen el 50% respecto a otro div

Tags: html, css

Intentaré explicar lo que quiero. Ahora mismo tengo 2 divs (div 1 de height 30px por ejemplo y div 2 que ocupa el resto de la pantalla) uno debajo del otro. Pero dentro del div 2 quiero tener otros 2 divs,uno debajo del otro (div 3 y div 4). Y estos quiero que ocupen el 50% respecto al div 2. ¿Hay alguna forma usando únicamente css y html (que se adapte a la pantalla)?

He probado con absolute pero se me pone el div 3 debajo del div 4 como si cogiese el 50% del viewport en vez del 50% del div.

Espero haberme explicado bien. Disculpadme pero el código no lo puedo compartir. Pero me gustaría un pequeño ejemplo de como hacerlo para después escalarlo a mi aplicación.

Ahora mismo tengo algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, quiero algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra como lo tienes en el código por favor

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes compartir tu código?

Comment: Simplemente se hace un cálculo de medidas en CSS con `calc()` y variables si sabes de ese atributo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con **display flex**, donde se aprecia la distribución de espacio entre contenedores así como su alineación, recuerda respetar y asignar tamaños de elementos hijos respecto al total del tamaño del contenedor padre.

```css
/*ELIMINAMOS ESTILOS POR DEFECTO*/

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*CUERPO DE LA PAGINA LE ASIGANKOS DISPLAY FLEX Y ALINEACION EN COLUMNA*/

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*PRIMER DIV*/

.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}


/*DIV2 QUE CONTIENE DETRO LOS OTROS DOS DIVS*/

.div2 {
  /*ASIGANOS DISPLAY FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  /*DIRECCION EN COLUMNA*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*CENTRAMOS EN EJE X*/
  align-items: center;
  /*CENTRAMOS EN EJE Y*/
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.div3 {
  width: 95%;
  /*AQUI ASIGNAS EL TAMAÑO DE ALTO SIN EXEDER EL LIMITE DEL PADRE CONTENDOR*/
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div4 {
  width: 95%;
  /*AQUI ASIGNAS EL TAMAÑO DE ALTO SIN EXEDER EL LIMITE DEL PADRE CONTENDOR*/
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
    <div class="div3">
      div3
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
      div4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Juega cambiando el tamaño **height y width** de los contenedores para apreciar su distribución, si no necesitas la alineacion centrada en X y Y la puedes eliminar.